# C# KeyDown not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox that I want to relocate when a key is pressed.
I'm making a game of pong. With the code below I want to make the paddle of player 1, which is a picturebox that should move up and down while a key is pressed. The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool upPressed, downPressed;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PongTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(upPressed){
            paddlePlayer1.Location = new Point(paddlePlayer1.Location.X, paddlePlayer1.Location.Y + 5);
        }
        if (downPressed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Numlock");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up){ 
            upPressed = true; 
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumLock)
        {
            downPressed = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up){ 
            upPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I used the Numlock to see if the problem was in the picture, this isn't the case. I've put the KeyPreview propery to true but this didnt solve it either. The timer does work properly.

I hope somebody here can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you post a complete code sample? e.g. the 'PongTimer' is never started, what is the interval of the timer?

Comment: Did you try the PreviewKeyDown event? If nothing in the form has keyboard focus, that should still work.

Comment: KeyPreview is not good enough to detect the cursor keys.  You would also have to override the IsInputKey() to tell Winforms that they should be used for input and not navigation.  Overriding ProcessCmdKey() is the better mousetrap.  Nothing yells out that you didn't forget to enable the timer.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in `Form1_KeyUp` and `Form1_KeyDown` to check whether it works as you expected?

Comment: I Don't know how to add the complete code, since i only have a Windows Form where i dragged and dropped the picturebox and timer.

Comment: The timer itself is enabled with interval set to 10

Comment: Is it correct that you only want to move a picturebox, based on a key press?

Comment: Yes, at this moment i only want it to move up, while i press the Up key.

Comment: You should press **and hold** the up key. Depending on how fast you release the UP key, the timer will fire after `Form1_KeyUp`, which means `upPressed` would be `false`.

Comment: @Alisson It is not good usability to ignore brief key presses.

Comment: The main issue with your code sample, is the use of booleans and a timer instead of using the current PictureBox location within the KeyDown event. Hopefully my example solved your problem. If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code example to move a PictureBox:

1. Drag/drop a PictureBox on a form (in this case Form1).
2. Change the Background color of the PictureBox to e.g. red. (This way it is visible during runtime).
3. Implement the KeyDown event of Form1 (in this case Form1_KeyDown).
4. Run the application.
5. Start pressing an arrow key and the PictureBox will move.

---

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
        int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) { x += 1; }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) { x -= 1; }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) { y -= 1; }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) { y += 1; }

        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Odrai, is it possible to make the int x and int y public and still produce the same effect?

Comment: That is possible, but you should only create a public x and y if you need these variables in another class.

Comment: I've copied this code and erased what i had before, however it's still not responding to my input unfortunatly

Comment: So i've made a complete blank form and added a picturebox with black background, this did work. Thanks!